# Replace directory contents during installation

Tags: installshield, installscript

I have a web application for which I implement an Installshield/InstallScript installer (i.e. no MSI).

The web application uses webpack, and I end up with a relatively short list of files which have some kind of hash in their names, like `30.1892376def7834bc2352.js`.

These file names change with every build. So when I run an update with the setup I end up with more and more files in the directory every time.

Is there a better way to handle the situation than hooking into some `OnInstalling` event and deleting the files?

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not been able to find a better way I set up the installer to delete the files in the `OnUpdateUIBefore` callback.

The initially proposed `OnInstalling` event is not suitable because temp files for feature to be installed are have already been copied and would be deleted, too.